# Extract MySQL data into XML using JSP

Tags: xml, jsp

I've got problems on extracting MySQL data into a XML format by using JSP. All my databases are inside MySQL and I dunno how to extract it using JSP, do I need to use some command in the JSP pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know JSP are used mainly for generating HTML/XHTML/XML with structure defined by the programmer - but not exactly by transforming MySQL query results. What You want is probably generating XML with JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding).

Basically You create some object(s) that will store result of querying (this is what Hibernate is used for), and then annotate them/describe binding with XML configuration, and return result of the processing.

If You're using Spring Framework that can be obtained by binding Your `@Entity` classes with JAXB, and returning them with action annotated with `@ResponseBody`. Let us know what is specific configuration in which You use JSP and maybe someone more experienced will give You more specific solution.

Comment: I solved the problem.Here is the codes.